# pg_dump from java not generating backup file

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to invoke pg_dump from java. Here is the command which I am trying to execute. But the the file specified in --file argument is not getting created.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.10_1/bin/pg_dump --format=t --verbose --file=/Users/abc/Downloads/backups/backup-1549946580007.backup --no-password
```

And here is the code which I am using to execute the same. I am using Apache commons exec to execute the command. I have also tried ProcessBuilder and Process to execute the same.

```
    cmd = "sh";
    cmdArg = "-c";
    pgCmdArg = System.getenv("POSTGRES_BIN") + "pg_dump";
    pgVerboseArg = "--verbose";
    fileArg = "--file=" + inputFile;
    noPassWordArg = "--no-password";
    Map<String, String> env=new HashMap<>();
    env.put("PGHOST", "localhost");
    env.put("PGUSER", dbUserName);
    env.put("PGPASSWORD", dbPass);
    env.put("PGPORT", "5432");
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CommandLine commandline = CommandLine.parse(cmd).addArgument(cmdArg).addArgument(pgCmdArg)
                        .addArgument("--format=t").addArgument(pgVerboseArg).addArgument(fileArg)
                        .addArgument(noPassWordArg).addArgument(dbName);

    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new 
    PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);
    exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
   int exitCode = exec.execute(commandline, env);
```

Any idea why the file is not getting created?

Comment: What does the output stream say? Do you check the error stream? Do you check the postgres logs?

Comment: Exit code is 0, no errors.

Comment: Examine the exit code and standard error. Why do you want the `pg_dump` tar format of all things?

Comment: @albe, was desperate to try out all options and get it working. Thats why I used tar. The exit code is 0 and there is no errors.The intended content of the file is there in outputstream. If I print System.out.println(outputStream.toString()), its printing all the content. Just that its not creating the file and writing the contents there. The folder is accessible.